# adding months to a date SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am trying to add months to an existing date in SQL. The new column displayed will have a followup column instead of a days column. Im getting an error in the select statement.can u help?

```
Create table auctions(
item varchar2(50),
datebought date,
datesold date,
days number
);
Insert into auctions values (‘Radio’,’12-MAY-2001’,’21-MAY-2001’,9);
Select item,datebought,datesold,ADD MONTHS(datesold,3)”followup” from auctions;
```

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php, http://ss64.com/ora/syntax.html

Answer (score 6):

Your usage of the add_months() function is incorrect. It's not two words, it's just one (with an underscore)

```
add_months(datesold, 1)
```

note the underscore `_` between `ADD` and `MONTHS`. It's function call not an operator.

Alternatively you could use:

```
datesold + INTERVAL '1' month
```

Although it's worth noting that the arithmetics with intervals is limited (if not broken) because it simply "increments" the month value of the date value. That can lead to invalid dates (e.g. from January to February). Although this is documented behaviour (see below links) I consider this a bug (the SQL standard requires those operations to "*Arithmetic obey the natural rules associated with dates and times and yield valid datetime or interval results according to the Gregorian calendar*")

See the manual for details:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions011.htm#i76717
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Another thing:

> *I am trying to add months to an existing date in SQL.*

Then why are you using an `INSERT` statement? To change the data of existing rows you should use `UPDATE`. So it seems what you are really after is something like this:

```
update auctions
   set datesold = add_months(datesold, 1)
where item = 'Radio';
```

Comment: +1 But it's probably worth noting that `add_months` and `+ interval '1' month` do not always work the same way.  For example, `add_months(date '2000-01-31', 1)` returns 2000-02-29.  But `date '2000-01-31' + interval '1' month` fails with `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

Comment: @jonearles: good point. Although I consider the behaviour of `+ interval '1' month'` a bug as it e.g. does not work for January 31st (Oracle tries to simply increment the month value which leads to an invalid February 31st). Other DBMS do get that right.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wrote: "...can lead to invalid dates (e.g. from January to February)..."  Many belated thanks. This answered everything.  I cannot believe the Oracle allows the interval to be so broken.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL has typographical quotation marks, not standard ones. E.g. `’` is not the same as `'`. Instead of delimiting a string value, those quotes become *part of* the value, at least for the particular SQL I have here to test with.

If this doesn't fix your problem, try posting the error you're getting in your question. Magical debugging isn't possible.

Comment: SQL> Select item,datebought,datesold,ADD MONTHS(datesold,3)"followup" from auctions;
Select item,datebought,datesold,ADD MONTHS(datesold,3)"followup" from auctions
                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: You are missing a comma after `ADD MONTHS`, though there are probably more errors. Please put your error details in your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to add months to a date in SQL:

```sql
select DATEADD(mm,1,getdate())
```

This might be a [useful link](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam2243-adding-months-to-a-date-in-sql.aspx).