# Query to retrieve books rented most in last 24 months

Tags: sql, oracle

how would I go about finding out the books that have been rented most in last 24 months?

```
 rentedBooks (rentid, bookid, dateout, datein)
```

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM RENTEDBOOKS, COUNT(BOOKID) WHERE DATEIN >= DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE());
```

But keep receiving an error mentioning invalid identifier :S

note: I am not using mysql!

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: You can't select from `count(bookid)` as a table. you probably want `select count(bookid) from ...`

Comment: Dateadd looks like tsql (SQL server not oracle)

Comment: oracle sql plus is what I'm using it is definitely dateadd

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT BOOKID, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM RENTEDBOOKS
WHERE DATEIN >= sysdate - interval '24' month
group by BOOKID
order by cnt desc;
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT BOOKID, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM RENTEDBOOKS
WHERE DATEIN >= add_months(sysdate, -24)
group by BOOKID
order by cnt desc;
```

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435245/adding-months-to-a-date-sql add_months might be safer than using interval.

Comment: simply I think the author does not need to know it that strict

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on with your WHERE clause (DATEADD, getdate), but the rest should look something like this...

```
SELECT BOOKID, COUNT(BOOKID) 
FROM RENTEDBOOKS
WHERE ...
GROUP BY BOOKID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATEIN >= DATEADD('m',-24, Date$());
```